# Stuck with DateTime Object name in Json API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, api

I am calling an API which is giving me a json response like

```
{
"symbol": "AAPL",
"stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
"timezone_name": "America/New_York",
"intraday": {
    "2018-11-21 15:59:00": {
        "open": "177.24",
        "close": "176.77",
        "high": "177.25",
        "low": "176.77",
        "volume": "430073"
    },
    "2018-11-21 15:58:00": {
        "open": "177.23",
        "close": "177.23",
        "high": "177.25",
        "low": "177.12",
        "volume": "188425"
    },
    "2018-11-21 15:57:00": {
        "open": "177.18",
        "close": "177.21",
        "high": "177.24",
        "low": "177.11",
        "volume": "163151"
    },
```

Now I want to access all data so I need to create an object of this but when I am using Json2cSharp converter then it gives me an object name which is invalid type.
So which type of object I should make so I can access all data regularly.
Please help.

Comment: Use VisualStudio's _"Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes"_, it will generate necessary classes for you.

Comment: @SeM, I couldnt find that Paste JSON as Classes in VS2013. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
public partial class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock_exchange_short")]
    public string StockExchangeShort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timezone_name")]
    public string TimezoneName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("intraday")]
    public Dictionary<string, Intraday> Intraday { get; set; }
}

public partial class Intraday
{
    [JsonProperty("open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("volume")]
    public long Volume { get; set; }
}
```

The tricky part is the `Intraday` property, because you have to use a dictionary to get all the values correctly.

I've used [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/) (which json2csharp is now joining forces with). If you want to play yourself a bit with the tool here's a link to the code: https://app.quicktype.io?share=DRgQz3PJVCLy4JR3JtGZ

There's a lot more code there if you change options in the right menu. You can set the **Output Features** to `Complete` and will get a really nice snippet. Including the usage. In that case, something like the below will be enough to get the json deserialized to your custom class.

```
var welcome = Welcome.FromJson(jsonString);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Karel Tamayo. It's working better and providing data as per our expectations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced same issues from SMS report API, i have asked them to modify response to the below object style. Converting a json array to C# array object is not possible under DeserializeObject. so I prefered List data structure.

```
 public class APIResponse
 {
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string stock_exchange_short { get; set; }
    public string timezone_name { get; set; }
    public List<IntradayLog> intraday { get; set; }
 }
public class IntradayLog
 {
    public float open { get; set; }
    public float close { get; set; }
    public float high { get; set; }
    public float low { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
 }

var apiLogJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(myAPIResponse);
```

**Update**
@Sem commets to use EDit => Paste Special => Paste Json As Classes,  i got this

[How to Paste](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/)

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string stock_exchange_short { get; set; }
    public string timezone_name { get; set; }
    public Intraday intraday { get; set; }
}

public class Intraday
{
    public _20181121155900 _20181121155900 { get; set; }
    public _20181121155800 _20181121155800 { get; set; }
    public _20181121155700 _20181121155700 { get; set; }
}

public class _20181121155900
{
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string close { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
}

public class _20181121155800
{
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string close { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
}

public class _20181121155700
{
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string close { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
}
```