# Deserialize Json when name is dynamic

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I use this simple API, https://exchangeratesapi.io/ and I test with this uri: https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-03-01&symbols=SEK.
I want to deserialize the 'rates' part. Here is one response sample
[image]

And here is the code

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "end_at", Order = 1)]
    public DateTime EndAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start_at", Order = 2)]
    public DateTime StartAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rates", Order = 3)]
    public Dictionary<string, Rate> Rates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "base", Order = 4)]
    public string Base { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public Dictionary<string, double> Fields{ get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Rate
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public double CurrencyRate { get; set; }
}
```

And I deserilize it like this

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRateHistory>(response.Content);
```

My problem is that that Fields is null. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you show us _how_ you deserialize the JSON? That is a crucial part of the problem :-)

Comment: @Matthijs  I just updated the question

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53447976/4425004

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr property rates is in array, deserializing an array is difficult, is it possible to change the datastructure as list and brigh that date part inside the rates as `[{ "Logdate": "2018-10-26", "SEK":9.823},{...}]`. so that it could be Deserialized easily.

Comment: Refer the comments given by Mr. SeM  under this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53447346/4425004   also the approach of doing so   is here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your key/value pair are not fixed and data must be configurable then Newtonsoft.json has one feature that to be use here and that is `[JsonExtensionData]`.  [Read more](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections)

> Extension data is now written when an object is serialized. Reading and writing extension data makes it possible to automatically round-trip all JSON without adding every property to the .NET type you’re deserializing to. Only declare the properties you’re interested in and let extension data do the rest.

In your case `rates` key have value as dynamic data so your `Rate` class will be

```
public class Rate
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can deserialize your response content as

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRate>(response.Content);
```